# How to get only the parent of the parent of the component

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, drag-and-drop, event-handling, flash-builder

I am trying to apply the glow filter to the parent container of the parent container of the child, the event comes from the child.

so: [parent] has [another parent] which has  [child]

Event is fired by the child and I only want to get the top level parent.

I have tried:

```
targetOwner.parent.parent.parent.filters = [glow];
```

but this applies the glow to all parent containers and I only need the top level one, is that even possible to achieve it this way? Any help appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The sole concept of `mc.parent.parent.filters = [glow]` works fine. Can you share your event handler and some other code, to see where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

you cant have a parent glow but the child not. you should divide the parent to two mocievlips, one will have the non-glowing childs, other will have the glowing parts of the parent.

Comment: This makes the whole thing much more complicated, basically I want to apply this effect to the parent container which holds the dragged items so when the dragged item is dragged to that container then it glows, but the structure of the containers is as follows: titledContainer>HGroup(target)>item so I would like only the titledContainer to glow @csomakk